# capture std::function by value

Tags: c++, lambda, crash

I use the following code:

```
struct WorkData
{
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(std::string)> Callback;

    WorkData(){};
    WorkData(const WorkData& other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        Callback = std::ref(other.Callback);
    }
};

WorkData data; // this is the data to pass to queue_task() function bellow
data.Callback = std::bind(&ResultProcessor::Handler, resProc, std::placeholders::_1);

template <typename Functor>
void queue_task(Functor& fn, WorkData& workData )
{
    group.run([&fn, workData](){
          workData.Callback("resultComming"); // runtime ERROR- access violation
    });
}
```

queue_task function queues work to be done asynchronously on another thread (by calling group.run(lambda) from above). The problem that I'm experiencing is that I get an access violation when trying to call workData.Callback().

The reason I make a copy of workData inside group.run() is because I want to capture workData by value so that when the group.run() lambda executes it has a copy of the state when queue_task() was called. I would expect that  workData.Callback() would execute on the instance of object passed on line:

```
data.Callback = std::bind(&ResultProcessor::Handler, resProc, std::placeholders::_1);
```

EDIT:  resProc from above is alive (not destroyed) when the crash line is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `std::ref` in your copy constructor means that you keep a reference to the old `WorkData`'s `Callback` member, not a copy.  You want `Callback = other.Callback` to make a copy to avoid an access violation (probably from accessing the old callback after it has been freed).  In order to keep a reference to `resProc` in the `std::function`, you need to use `std::ref(resProc)` in the call to `std::bind`.

Comment: I jus aded the EDIT in my question. I use std::ref because otherwise I end up calling workData.Callback("resultComming") on a different instance of ResultProcessor

Comment: In that case, you need to use `std::ref` on the `ResultProcessor`, not the function object itself.  I.e., in your last code block, you should have `std::ref(resProc)` and then use a true copy of the `std::function` in your copy constructor.

Comment: ResultProcessor instance is transmitted alongside std::function<void(std::string)> Callback as part of WorkData in  queue_task() interface

Comment: I don't see that in your code: you are passing in the `WorkData` object but not the `ResultProcessor` in `queue_task`.

Comment: there is a line of code WorkData data, where I initialize data.Callback. That data I call to queue_task

Comment: Yes, and that initializes `Callback` to an `std::function` that contains a copy of `resProc`, not a reference to it.

Comment: In that case, you need `std::bind(&ResultProcessor::Handler, std::ref(resProc), std::placeholders::_1)`.

Comment: I just edited the answer to add the result of the discussion.